# PHP Session doesn't update

Tags: php, session

I've had this problem for more than a month now. Put it away in the corner because I thought I won't have to deal with it again. Or so I thought. My login feature doesn't work as I expected, `$_SESSION` doesn't update when I return to home page. I'm thinking it has to do with my `index.php` structure but I'm not sure. Even if it was the case I don't even know to fix it either. Here's my code:

login.php

```php
<?php

// validate login
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if ($user = validate_login($username, $password)) {
        $_SESSION['user']['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['user']['role'] = $user['role'];
        $_SESSION['errors'] = false; 
        // redirect to home
        header('Location: index.php?page=home');
    }

    else {
        $_SESSION['errors'] = 'stuff';
    }

   
}

<html stuff here>
?>
```

index.php

```php
<?php
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user'] = array();
    $_SESSION['user']['username'] = '';
    $_SESSION['user']['role'] = 2; // 2: guest, 1: admin, 0: user
    $_SESSION['user']['identity'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // IP address
    $_SESSION['errors'] = false;
}
require 'global.php';
require 'dao/pdo.php';

get_header();
$page = $_GET['page'] ?? 'home';
$path = "site/{$page}.php";

if (file_exists($path)) {
?>
    <!-- css -->
    <style>
        <?php include "./content/css/{$page}.css" ?>
    </style>
    <!-- js -->
    <script src="./content/js/<?php echo $page ?>.js"></script>
<?php
    require $path; //login.php will be loaded here
} else {
    echo "Page doesn't exist";
}

?>
<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `login.php` must have `session_start()` called before it can use sessions.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned it but `login.php` will be loaded on the line `require $path;` So `session_start()` should've already been called by then right?

Comment: What does $path equal? You sure it equals ```site/login.php```?

Comment: @Fly_Moe Yup. I have tested and added a bunch of pages. `$_SESSION` worked and did updated while I was on `login.php` but after redirect `$_SESSION` revert back to default values

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the source of the problem but I don't know why it happen (will update the post if I found out why)

```php
    $_SESSION['user'] = array();
    $_SESSION['user']['username'] = '';
    $_SESSION['user']['role'] = 2; // 2: guest, 1: admin, 0: user
    $_SESSION['user']['identity'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // IP address
    $_SESSION['errors'] = false;
```

`$_SESSION['user']` is defined and initialized in `index.php`. But for some reason `login.php` can't change defined variables. New variables still works.

`login.php`

```php
    if ($user = validate_login($username, $password)) {
        $_SESSION['user']['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['user']['role'] = $user['role'];
        $_SESSION['errors'] = false; 
        // redirect to home
        header('Location: index.php?page=home');
    }
```

What I did:

```php
    if ($user = validate_login($username, $password)) {
        //moved $_SESSION[user] elements outside
        $_SESSION['username'] = $user['username'];  //new variable
        $_SESSION['role'] = $user['role'];  //new variable
        $_SESSION['errors'] = false;
        // redirect to home
        header('Location: index.php?page=home');
    }
```